# How to link to specific anchor in table with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this jquery plugin:

http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/07/20/Expand-table-rows-with-jQuery-jExpand-plugin.aspx

I have anchors in the code such as:

```
<a name="art" id="art2"></a> Articles
```

How can I open that particular row then? In other words, when a user clicks a link from another page to this landing page I would like the appropriate row to open up based on the anchor tag.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

In your document.ready you can call the click event of that anchor, like this:

```
$(function() {
  if(document.location.hash != '')
    $(document.location.hash).click();
});
```

This would make for example `www.yoursite.com/yourPage.htm#art2` perform a click on that link causing it to open.  Just make sure the above code is **after** your click event handler, so it actually does something on click :)

If you're landing on `#art` using the named anchor, similar approach:

```
$(function() {
  if(document.location.hash != '')
    $('a[name="' + document.location.hash.replace('#','') + '"]').click();
});
```

Comment: @Joel - Yep, I believe that's consistent across all browsers.

Comment: I can't get that to work. Made a test page here:

http://www.libraries.uc.edu/tests/table_rows.html

Such that your example would be:
http://www.libraries.uc.edu/tests/table_rows.html#art2

Comment: @LisaH - It's currently inside the click handler `$("#report tr.odd").click(function(){`, it needs to be moved outside of there, and no need for the `$(function() { });` around it since you're already in document.ready :)